# My client server code is not working correctly

Tags: c++, tcp

I get some code of a client server program and i modify it by my own . But i could not find out why my code is not working correctly. Compilation is fine but getting an abort error in the client ? I ahve tried myself and i am new to programming.So please if you can have a look on the give client server code below and check whats the proble.

```
//Client side code 

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include "client.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
tcp_client::tcp_client()
{}

tcp_client::~tcp_client()
{}
int tcp_client::start_listening()

{

    WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout<<"Client: Error at socket(): %ld.\n"<< WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    clientService.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if (connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"Client: Failed to connect\0";
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int tcp_client::start_sending()
{

    int bytesSent;
    int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;

    std::vector<double> m_vector;
    uint32_t  nlength =0;
    std::vector<double> m_vector1(nlength/sizeof(double)); 


    for( int i = 0; i <100; i++)
    {    
        m_vector.push_back(i);
    }

    uint32_t siz = (m_vector.size())*sizeof(double);



    int total_bytes = 0;
    int count=0;


    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {  

        bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)&siz, 4, 0);
        assert (bytesSent == sizeof (uint32_t));
        std::cout<<"length information is in:"<<bytesSent<<"bytes"<<std::endl;

        bytesSent = send(ConnectSocket,(char*)m_vector.data(), siz, 0);
        total_bytes = total_bytes+bytesSent;

        std::cout<<"Client: Bytes sent:"<<total_bytes<<std::endl;
    }

    closesocket (ConnectSocket);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{

    std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();

    tcp_client a;
    a.start_listening();
    a.start_sending();

    std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();
    std::cout << "CPU time used: "<< 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " ms\n";

    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

// Client.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
class tcp_client
{

public:
    tcp_client();
    virtual ~tcp_client();
    int start_listening();
    int start_sending();

protected:

   SOCKET ConnectSocket; // client Socket
   };
```

//server code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include "server.h"

using namespace std;
 tcp_server::tcp_server()
{}

tcp_server::~tcp_server()
{}

int tcp_server::start_listening()
{

    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);


    if (wsaerr != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"server starting...."<<std::endl;
    }


    m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (m_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout<<"Server: Error at socket(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }


    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;

    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    service.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if (bind(m_socket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"Server: bind() failed:"<< WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(m_socket);
        return 0;
    }


    if (listen(m_socket, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout<<"Server: listen(): Error listening on socket "<< WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }

    SOCKET AcceptSocket;

    while (1)
    {
        AcceptSocket = SOCKET_ERROR;
        while (AcceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            AcceptSocket = accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL);
        }

        cout<<"Server: Client Connected"<<std::endl;
        m_socket = AcceptSocket;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

int tcp_server::start_receiving()
{

    int bytesSent;
    int bytesRecv;
    uint32_t  nlength =0;
    int total_br =0;
    std::vector<double> m_vector(nlength/sizeof(double));


    std::clock_t c_start=0;

    int count =0;

    while(1)
    {

        int length_received = recv(m_socket,(char*)&nlength, 4, 0); 
        m_vector.resize(nlength/sizeof(double));
        bytesRecv = recv(m_socket,(char*)m_vector.data(), nlength, 0);


        if(bytesRecv > 0)
        {
            total_br = total_br + bytesRecv;

            cout<<"Server: Received bytes are"<<total_br<<std::endl;
        }
            else
        {
            std::cout<<"Data Receiving has finished"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }

}
closesocket (m_socket);
WSACleanup();   
return total_br;
}

int main()

{
    std::clock_t c_start = std::clock();
    tcp_server a;
    a.start_listening();
    int byte= a.start_receiving();
    std::cout<<"total byte received are"<<byte;

    std::clock_t c_end = std::clock();
    std::cout << "CPU time used: "<< 1000.0 * (c_end-c_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< " ms\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

//server.h

```
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
class tcp_server
{

public:
    tcp_server();
    virtual ~tcp_server();
    int start_listening();
    int start_receiving();

protected:

   SOCKET m_socket; // Server Socket
    };
```

Comment: You have a minor security bug in your server code. If I connect to your server port and send 0xffffffff for nLength, your code will attempt to allocate 4GB for the subsequent m_vector.resize call. Also, recv() can and will return partial data. You should loop on calling recv() until you have received all the bytes. Or use MSG_WAIT flag.

Comment: how do you run the program?

Comment: @selbie I have tried with MSG_WAITALL flag but result is same. My question is that if i am sending length and data each time from client then why server is not receiving data with prefix length each time ? Why should i only keep recv calling by loop why not length recv as well? because they are not separte when length will read than only that much data can be received. Kindly can you please correct the mistake if possible ? This code was working fine without class but after implementing with class i have problem.

Comment: @jfly First server and then client

Comment: if the data is large than your recv_buffer, the server program can't receive all the data in one chunk, more data will be saved in the kernel for your next call to `recv`. So you should loop on calling `recv()`. But this may be not the cause of abort.

Comment: What jfly said. You should always assume that recv() might return anything from 1..N.  If you assume that recv() might actually return "1" each time you call it, then you'll structure your code accordingly to loop or use MSG_WAITALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete this line in the client.cpp, it will work:

```
SOCKET ConnectSocket;
```

I ran the code after deleting this line previously, so it worked fine.

This line means you define a local variable `ConnectSocket` within the scope of function `start_listening()`, **this local variable shadows the member variable**. it seems you assign a valid file descriptor to the member variable, but the member variable `ConnectSocket` is always uninitialized, so the `send()` fails.

Comment: I've found the problem, see my EDIT.